# Pandas DataFrame.resample monthly offset from particular day of month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have a DataFrame `df` with sporadic daily business day rows (i.e., there is not always a row for every business day.)

For each row in `df` I want to create a historical resampled mean `dfm` going back one month at a time.  For example, if I have a row for `2018-02-22` then I want rolling means for rows in the following date ranges:

- `2018-01-23 : 2018-02-22`
- `2017-12-23 : 2018-01-22`
- `2017-11-23 : 2017-12-22`
- etc.

But I can't see a way to keep this pegged to the particular day of the month using [conventional offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).  For example, if I do:

```
dfm = df.resample('30D').mean()
```

Then we see two problems:

1. It references the beginning of the DataFrame.  In fact, I can't find a way to force `.resample()` to peg itself to the end of the DataFrame – even if I have it operate on `df_reversed = df.loc[:'2018-02-22'].iloc[::-1]`.  Is there a way to "peg" the resampling to something other than the earliest date in the DataFrame?  (And ideally pegged to each particular row as I run some lambda on the associated historical resampling from each row's date?)
2. It will drift over time, because not every month is 30 days long.  So as I go back in time I will find that the interval 12 "months" prior ends `2017-02-27`, not `2017-02-22` like I want.

Knowing that I want to resample by non-overlapping "months," the second problem can be well-defined for month days 29-31: For example, if I ask to resample for '2018-03-31' then the date ranges would end at the end of each preceding month:

- `2018-03-01 : 2018-03-31`
- `2018-02-01 : 2018-02-28`
- `2018-01-01 : 2018-02-31`
- etc.

Though again, I don't know: is there a good or easy way to do this in pandas?

---

#### tl;dr:

Given something like the following:

```
someperiods = 20 # this can be a number of days covering many years
somefrequency = '8D' # this can vary from 1D to maybe 10D
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-03', periods=someperiods, freq=somefrequency)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': rng.day}, index=rng) # x in practice is exogenous data

from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df['MonthPrior'] = df.index.to_pydatetime() + DateOffset(months=-1)
```

Now:

For each row in `df`: calculate `df['PreviousMonthMean']` = rolling average of all `df.x` in range `[df.MonthPrior, df.index)`.  In this example the resulting DataFrame would be:

```
Index       x   MonthPrior  PreviousMonthMean
2017-01-03  3   2016-12-03  NaN
2017-01-11  11  2016-12-11  3
2017-01-19  19  2016-12-19  7
2017-01-27  27  2016-12-27  11
2017-02-04  4   2017-01-04  19
2017-02-12  12  2017-01-12  16.66666667
2017-02-20  20  2017-01-20  14.33333333
2017-02-28  28  2017-01-28  12
2017-03-08  8   2017-02-08  20
2017-03-16  16  2017-02-16  18.66666667
2017-03-24  24  2017-02-24  17.33333333
2017-04-01  1   2017-03-01  16
2017-04-09  9   2017-03-09  13.66666667
2017-04-17  17  2017-03-17  11.33333333
2017-04-25  25  2017-03-25  9
2017-05-03  3   2017-04-03  17
2017-05-11  11  2017-04-11  15
2017-05-19  19  2017-04-19  13
2017-05-27  27  2017-04-27  11
2017-06-04  4   2017-05-04  19
```

If we can get that far, then I need to find an efficient way to iterate that so that for each row in `df` I can aggregate consecutive but *non-overlapping* `df['PreviousMonthMean']` values going back one calendar month at a time from the given DateTimeIndex....

Comment: I would do this by breaking the date in to year, month and day.  Hold day constant and add subtract from month.  Then add the parts back together to get back a datetime dtype.